# XSD scheme syntax and gSoap

Tags: c++, c, xml, xsd, gsoap

I have a question, is this XSD syntax valid? Because when I use gSOAP, it pruduces me warnings because it creates struct (C/C++ code), which consists two other structs with the same name (name C), and then when I try to compile that code in c/c++ compiler it prodeces errors (because of the struct with the same name inside one struct). Is here any possibility how to solve this without touching the XSD file?

```
<complexType name="A">
<choice>
<sequence>
<element name="B" type="base64Binary"/>
<element name="C" type="base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
<any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
<sequence>
<element name="C" type="base64Binary"/>
<any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
</choice>
</complexType>
```

in gSOAP I create it using: `wsdl2h.exe -oSoap.h -s -y -c a.wsdl b.wsdl ...` and

`soapcpp2.exe -C -L -n -x -w -c -d.\source Soap.h`

Comment: @KeineLust, gSoap produces C/C++ code, where appears the problem that two structs inside one struct have the same name.

Comment: ok ;) can you show those warnings?

Comment: ```error: redefinition of 'struct a::c'``` and
```error: previous definition of 'struct a::c'```

Comment: @МартинБее to be accurate, those are not merely warnings, they are errors.

Comment: @user2079303, I agree sorry, warnings I get from gSoap compiler, it creates c/c++ code from xml with warning, and then this code produces error after compilation in c/c++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's valid XSD syntax; it just looks like a case that your code generator isn't able to handle.

Comment: Sorry, this answer incorrect. Yes, it is valid XSD. But the code generator is not faulting on this. It is just a warning. I worked with code like this and I can attest that the code generators handle this XSD fine.

Answer (score 0):

The soapcpp2 tool only complains, but the generated code works by design. I worked on this and tested it.

Here is what I get generated by soapcpp2:

```
class ns__A
{ public:
//  BEGIN CHOICE <xs:choice>
/// @note <xs:choice> with embedded <xs:sequence> or <xs:group> prevents the use of a union for <xs:choice>. Instead of being members of a union, the following members are declared optional. Only one member should be non-NULL by choice.
//  BEGIN SEQUENCE <xs:sequence>
/// Element "B" of XSD type xs:base64Binary.
    xsd__base64Binary*                   B                              nullptr;    ///< Required nillable (xsi:nil when NULL) element.
/// Element "C" of XSD type xs:base64Binary.
    xsd__base64Binary*                   C                             ;    ///< Required element.
/// Size of the array of XML or DOM nodes is 0..unbounded.
    std::vector<_XML                   > __any                         0;   ///< Catch any element content in XML string.
//  END OF SEQUENCE
//  BEGIN SEQUENCE <xs:sequence>
/// Element "C" of XSD type xs:base64Binary.
    xsd__base64Binary*                   C                              nullptr;    ///< Required nillable (xsi:nil when NULL) element.
/// Size of the array of XML or DOM nodes is 0..unbounded.
    std::vector<_XML                   > __any                         0;   ///< Catch any element content in XML string.
//  END OF SEQUENCE
//  END OF CHOICE
/// A handle to the soap struct context that manages this instance when instantiated by a context or NULL otherwise (automatically set).
    struct soap                         *soap                          ;
};
```

The reason for the "issue" reported by soapcpp2 is that the streaming serializer can't distinguish the choices for `C`. So both are encoded. The second `C` is renamed `C_` and is never used to deserialize data.

Simple explanation: you're fine.